# Eagle Library for schematics drawing

Tags: schematics, eaglecad

I realise Eagle is primarily a PCB layout tool, but I would like to use the software to draw schematics I will use in reports. I won't be using these schematics for any PCB layout.

What I need, which is not included in the standard library is a proper DC and AC voltage source like these I found on a [SparkFun tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-read-a-schematic/schematic-symbols-part-1):
[image: AC and DC source]

If there's no such library, is there an easy way to draw these symbols for my own library?

Comment: I do not see existing ready to use symbols in standard Eagle libraries; these symbols are relatively easy to create in Eagle library editor. After you draw the symbol, add dummy 2-pin package the device (e.g. 2 through-hole pads), and connect these pads to pins in order to have complete device without errors.

Comment: [Here's a decent guide on symbol creation in Eagle](https://learn.adafruit.com/ktowns-ultimate-creating-parts-in-eagle-tutorial/the-symbol-editor). FWIW, I find it much faster and easier to create symbols in [KiCad](https://kicad.org/), so you might want to check that out as well. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: Thank you uint128, I actually have KiCad installed so I think I will definitely give that a try for my next project. But my current is due for Monday so there's no time to waste here.